# transform flattened json into date object in snowfalke

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know how to flatten the below object, but wondering how I can pass the values in as I flatten them to create a date

What I have:

```
 "dateRange": {
            "start": {
                "month": 9,
                "day": 2,
                "year": 2020
            }
```

What I want

```
2020-09-02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DATE_FROM_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_from_parts.html)

```
DATE_FROM_PART(year,month,day)
```

or for you object

```
DATE_FROM_PART(f.value:dateRange:start:year, f.value:dateRange:start:month, f.value:dateRange:start:year)
```

if the flatten looked like `table(flatten(input=> <something>) f`

Comment: THAT's IT THANK YOU - I have to wait 10min to approve - much appreciated